# grep AND OR operators combined with IP addresses

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to find a way of streamlining my grep searches and be more granualar.

An example of what I want to achieve: a netstat output searching for a particular IP AND the word established OR another IP AND another string.

Without the OR statement, I could work around this by running another grep but I 'need' the OR statement.

I'm content that `grep 'string1\|string2'` would perform an OR query and `grep 'string1.*string2 *\|string3'` would find "string1 and string2" or "string3". Throwing an IP into the mix has me at a loss, the decimals get treated as another AND statement (I think?) and using `\` as an escape character doesn't seem to work either. Can anyone explain how I would achieve this?

What I am using so far:

```
grep -i '1\.2\.3\.4.*established*\|5\.6.\7\.8.*listening*' netstatoutput.txt
```

Comment: Note that `established*` matches "establishe" followed by zero or more "d". You may have intended `established.*`

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, good point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using `grep -E` for the extended regexes (fewer backslashes).

Use parentheses for grouping:

```
grep -Ei '(1\.2\.3\.4.*established)|(5\.6.\7\.8.*listening)' netstatoutput.txt
```

Or use the `-e` option

```
grep -Ei -e '1\.2\.3\.4.*established' -e '5\.6.\7\.8.*listening' netstatoutput.txt
```

Comment: Ah, I never knew parenthesis were possible in this kind of search. Both work exactly as I need, thanks!